# Very short PhD Thesis by famous people

Tags: phd, thesis

I read that John Nash had a very short PhD Dissertation. A mere 27 pages. See this link:

http://www.princeton.edu/mudd/news/faq/topics/Non-Cooperative_Games_Nash.pdf

Are there other famous people with such short PhD theses? Anyone breaks this 27 page record?

Comment: I can't for the life of me find a reference at this point, but I remember reading that Alzheimer's thesis was 11 pages. *(but, you know, different times and such)*

Comment: Assuming it is a math thesis, this has been answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54775/what-is-the-shortest-ph-d-thesis. There is a reference in that question to a 9 page thesis.

Comment: I do not see how this is going to be anything but a random list of short theses with little value to anyone.

Comment: @StrongBad: I agree, asking for the shortest PhD thesis would be a way to limit the list, as only answers beating the current leader would be acceptable (and such questions do work on many Stack Exchanges), however things get problematic here as there is the another diffuse criterion of fame (unless one argues that having the shortest PhD thesis in history alone suffices to make you famous).

Comment: @StrongBad: Are you saying that the PhD theses of Nash, Alzheimer & Barry Mazur are of little value to anyone? I wasn't looking for Crappy Thesis by Unknown Nobody at University of Boondocksville. Luckily no one has even proposed such candidates.

Comment: @curious_cat no, the theses have value, what I do not see is the value of listing them.

Comment: @StrongBad Mere Curiosity. Not claiming this list will help save the world. I hope one can admit 17 pages is an Outlier so far as PhD's go & think of this as an enumeration of interesting outliers. Kinda in the same vein as knowing Feynman painted nudes, picked locks & played Bongos.

Comment: @curious_cat Sounds like [boat programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about) to me

Answer (score 4):

Barry Mazur's thesis "On Embeddings of Spheres" runs 17 pages, as far as I can tell from the paywalled source here: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02559532

Comment: There is some debate about that over at [MO.SE](http://mathoverflow.net/a/54785) with a page count as low as 5 and as high as 30.