# Has there ever been a pure mathematics thesis longer than 909 pages?

Tags: thesis, mathematics

When I heard that a friend of mine finished his PhD thesis with 909 pages, I wondered if there has ever been a longer thesis in (pure) mathematics?

Comment: See  http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46050/very-short-phd-thesis-by-famous-people for why questions like this are a bad fit.

Comment: @StrongBad What would you do if you wanted to answer this question?

Comment: Now that has the potential to be a good question for this site: soemthing like how to find statistics about theses in Math. But for an "exact" answer maybe maybe ask on a Purr Math email list server.

Comment: The answer to the question as asked is yes. For instance, in MathSciNet you find [MR2685954](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2685954) Thesis. Hugger, Jens. Computational aspects and adaptive solution methods in the finite element method for non-linear, parametrized problems. Thesis (Ph.D.)–University of Maryland, College Park. 1990. 1040 pp. ProQuest LLC.

Comment: MathSciNet indexes data from thesis, as provided by ProQuest LLC. It does not yet catalogue theses from outside the States. I do not know of any reasonable way of looking for global statistics or "records".

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you! How did you query MathSciNet for this information?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo The reason is: Although I am impressed that found this so quickly, I still want to solve the question for pure math.

Comment: Your question title and the content do not match-up.  First says, what is the longest paper in maths, the second says, is there anything longer than this one?

Comment: @Deleuze As it is probably not possible to give a conclusive argument for what "the longest" thesis is, I tried to make a bounty with a reasonable condition. I am still interested in solving the original question of the title.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is an issue (not familiar with the specific rules) but the question and the description of the bounty don't seem to match up. The question is polar (either there has been or there hasn't been). The description of the bounty allows for a third response (effectively, "I don't know, but this is why I'd consider it unlikely to be yes").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure that this is a good question, because the length of a thesis is obviously highly dependent on factors such as line spacing.

Having said that, it is possible to give a definitive answer to the question as written, even in the restrictive form asking about pure mathematics:

> **Yes.**

From MathSciNet:

> Lan, Kai-Wen Arithmetic compactifications of PEL-type Shimura varieties. Thesis (Ph.D.)–Harvard University. 2008. 1077 pp.

[Here it is](http://math.umn.edu/~kwlan/articles/cpt-PEL-type-thesis.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! You're of course right that page numbers are a very rough indicators of length (actually, the thesis you mentioned has large margins), but it seems to be the only measure for it is reasonable to find information.